# How to tell if they connected through domain name or IP in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I know that's a confusing title but let me explain.  I'm working on a website and I want it to look differently depending on if they used the ip or example.com in the address bar. Is it possible to get what address they used in PHP? I know you can change it with header('Location:example.com'); but I need to know how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print out

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Servers are **always** accessed by their IP addresses. If someone types in the hostname 'example.org' the device will resolve it using a DNS server (large list of hostnames and their respective ip addresses), the DNS server will give the device the IP address and the device will connect to that IP.

TCP/IPv4 packets can only be sent to 32-bit ipv4 addresses.

TCP/IPv6 packets can only be sent to 128-bit ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score -1):

On the page you want to know from what location a visitor came in from, do this:

`var_dump($_SERVER);`

You will see all the `$_SERVER` values you'll use to get different values you require.